# How can I fix this error given to me by my code?

Tags: python

I've been reading self-taught programmer and recently got to the part of the book where you code hangman. I've copied the code in the book perfectly yet I'm hit with a syntax error.

`SyntaxError: invalid escape sequence \`

This is the code:

```
def hangman (word)
    wrong = 0
    stages = ["",
             "________        ",
             "|               ",
             "|        |      ",
             "|        0      ",
             "|       /|\     ",
             "|       / \     ",
             "|               "
              ]
    rletters = list(word)
    board = ["__"] * len(word)
    win = False
    print("Welcome to Hangman")
    while wrong < len(stages) - 1:
        print("\n")
        msg = "Guess a letter"
        char = input(msg)
        if char in rletters:
            cind = rletters \
                   .index(char)
            board[cind] = char
            rletters[cind] = '$'
        else:
            wrong += 1
        print((" ".join(board)))
        e = wrong + 1
        print("\n"
              .join(stages[0: e]))
        if "__" not in board:
            print("You win!")
            print(" ".join(board))
            win = True
            break
    if not win:
        print("\n"
              .join(stages[0: \
              wrong]))
        print("You lose! It was {}."
              .format(word))

hangman("cat")
```

Comment: Are you sure you have copied the whole code correctly?

Comment: Could be the hangman's right arm and leg, is it meant to be `\\\`?

Comment: What happened when you tried putting `python syntaxerror invalid escape sequence` into a search engine? What book are you learning from, and what did it say about `\` symbols within strings (this should have been much earlier in the book, if it's written in a reasonable way)? What happened when you tried looking at the code where the error is pointing?

Comment: @Gamma032 good job; you correctly spotted the problem where three people in the answer section were all incorrect. This boils down to either a simple typo or a fundamental misunderstanding that is best cleared up by OP's reference material (or a better source); Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation. Voting to close.

Comment: Upon review, actually `\ ` works just fine inside a string. I checked the source code for the post and the code block was incorrectly posted - I have fixed it. It appears that OP has possibly missed the `:` on the first line; if so, that's just a typo (and also doesn't match the error message described). No matter what, this isn't a question that needs to stay open.

Comment: In the future, OP: please [show complete error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough), formatted as code, and make sure you understand the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). If you use triple backticks for your code blocks, you must have them on a line by themselves before and after the code.

Comment: Actually - hold on. What version of Python are you using? What happens if you try just `'\ '` by itself? This has historically worked in Python, but very recent changes to the parser may have affected the behaviour. I can't find a clear indication of this in the documentation or the PEPs, but 3.9 changes the fundamental approach that Python takes for interpreting source code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code  and its working without error:

```
def hangman(word):  
  wrong = 0
  stages = ["",
           "________        ",
           "|               ",
           "|        |      ",
           "|        0      ",
           "|       /|\     ",
           "|       / \     ",
           "|               "
            ]
  rletters = list(word)
  board = ["__"] * len(word)
  win = False
  print("Welcome to Hangman")
  while wrong < len(stages) - 1:
      print("\n")
      msg = "Guess a letter"
      char = input(msg)
      if char in rletters:
          cind = rletters \
                 .index(char)
          board[cind] = char
          rletters[cind] = '$'
      else:
          wrong += 1
      print((" ".join(board)))
      e = wrong + 1
      print("\n"
            .join(stages[0: e]))
      if "__" not in board:
          print("You win!")
          print(" ".join(board))
          win = True
          break
  if not win:
      print("\n"
            .join(stages[0: \
            wrong]))
      print("You lose! It was {}."
            .format(word))

hangman("cat")
```

Things I modified :

- Hangman function was not defined     `def hangman(word):`
- removed the additional triple code from the end of the program